# Tesseract-OCR is unable to find text in SOME images

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, text-extraction, python-tesseract

I have been using tesseract for text extraction from images. But due to some unknown reasons, it is unable to extract text from some images even if the image is clean. I am unable to find the reason for this. Is there anything that i am missing in preprocessing?

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
text = image_to_string('/path/to/image')
```

result: " "

this code is working fine with other images, But not with this image.

original image: [image: a government document]

Comment: Have you tried thresholding the image?

Comment: thresholding for what?

Comment: Tesseract works best with black text on white background

Comment: Please don't post personal information (that may not even be yours).

Comment: @dbc Sorry I didn't notice that. Will keep this in mind.